# Printing to PDF - how to avoid automatic display of screen to request save location?

Tags: pdf, printing, vb6

I'm working on a legacy application and trying to get VB6 to send printed output to a pdf printer (Nitro). The output from the application should end up printed into a pdf file in a specific location/filename.

**Issue:**

When I make a call to any `Printer` function, it pops up a dialogue box but I don't see a way for me to set the dialogue box's default path and filename. Is there a way to do this?

Even if i create my own dialogue box, as soon as any function call to `Printer` happens, it pops up a dialogue box.

Line of code that is popping up the dialogue box:

```
'How do I set the dialogue box it opens here to a default filename/location? 
Printer.PaintPicture .Picture, .Left + lngAddToLeft, .Top + lngAddToTop, .Width, .Height
```

Comment: You can [specify output PDF file with API calls only](https://github.com/VBForumsCommunity/vbimg2pdf/blob/master/mdPrintImages.bas#L152) so cannot use built-in `Printer` object.

Answer (score 5):

first you must set your system's default printer to "Nitro's Printer Name"

code below can help u to do this

```
Private Sub set_Nitro_As_Default()
 Dim prn As Printer
  If Printers.Count > 0 Then
    For Each prn In Printers
       If prn.DeviceName = [Nitro Printer Name] Then 'printer that u want to use
         Set Printer = prn
         Exit For
       End If
    Next prn
  End If
End Sub
```

to print some text,label or Graphical objects you must add an picturebox to your project .it contains all objects you want to print.

after you prepare all objects such as label or shape and every thing ready for print call this sub to save your picturebox image in a temp bmp file

```
'add this declaration on top of your project 
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                         ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

 Private Const WM_PAINT = &HF
 Private Const WM_PRINT = &H317
 Private Const PRF_CLIENT = &H4&    ' Draw the window's client area
 Private Const PRF_CHILDREN = &H10& ' Draw all visible child
 Private Const PRF_OWNED = &H20&    ' Draw all owned windows

'this function save PicBox image in FileName path
'PicBox Contain All thing which you want to print
Public Sub SavePictureBox(PicBox As PictureBox, FileName As String)
  Dim rv As Long
  Dim ar As Boolean

  With PicBox
  'Save ReDraw value
    ar = .AutoRedraw
         .AutoRedraw = True

  'Draw controls to picture box
    rv = SendMessage(.hwnd, WM_PAINT, .hdc, 0)
    rv = SendMessage(.hwnd, WM_PRINT, .hdc, _
                      PRF_CHILDREN Or PRF_CLIENT Or PRF_OWNED)

  'save picture box
      SavePicture .Image, FileName

         .Cls

         'Restore ReDraw
         .AutoRedraw = ar
  End With
End Sub
```

you must add some thing like this to your main print command

```
private sub iPrint()
   'firstly set your intended printer as default    
    call set_Nitro_As_Default
   'set some Generic setting
    Printer.PrintQuality = vbPRPQHigh
    Printer.PaperSize = vbPRPSA4

    for i=1 to [your intended page count]

     'do some thing for Arrange your labels and objects to make it ready to print
     'after prepare your all thing on picturebox
       call SavePictureBox([printed PictureBox], App.path & "\tmp.bmp")

     'print this page 
     'note that you can set margin and your printed page size
       Printer.PaintPicture LoadPicture(App.Path & "\tmp.bmp"), 0, 0, _
                            LoadPicture(App.Path & "\tmp.bmp").Width, _
                            LoadPicture(App.Path & "\tmp.bmp").Height, _
                            0, 0, _
                            Printer.Width, _
                            Printer.Height

       Printer.NewPage
     next i

       Printer.EndDoc

end sub
```

its done